# Regex To clear out a WORD HTML Tag

Tags: php, regex

I have some text that has been parsed from word, and I am trying to get the HYPERLINK section removed.  I have tried the following, what am I doing wrong?

```
preg_replace("/(HYPERLINK "\"{2})/", "", $input_string);
```

Here is an example of what I would like to happen.

```
words words words HYPERLINK "https://stackoverflow.com" https://stackoverflow.com words words words
```

Should become

```
words words words https://stackoverflow.com words words words
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the following pattern and replace with an empty string:

```
/HYPERLINK +"[^"]+" */
```

[`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/qP7eY3/1)

**PHP**

`preg_replace('/HYPERLINK +"[^"]+" */', "", $input_string);`

**EXPLANATION**

```
  NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  HYPERLINK                'HYPERLINK'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   +                       ' ' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
```

Check also [`The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/1519058) to read more about regexes

Comment: Thank you,  I am having trouble figuring out this regex stuff.  Need to read more about it.

Comment: This is the best answer ^^^^

Answer (score 1):

**preg replace**

```
echo preg_replace('/HYPERLINK +"[^"]+" */', "", $input_string); // should do it
```

[learn regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

**explanation**

- matches the character   literally
- Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- " matches the characters " literally
- [^"]+ match a single character not present in the list below
- Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- " a single character in the list " literally (case sensitive)
- " matches the characters " literally

**old solution**

```
$input_string = 'words words words HYPERLINK "https://stackoverflow.com" https://stackoverflow.com words words words';  

$words = explode(' ', $input_string);
foreach (array_keys($words, 'HYPERLINK') as $key) {
  unset($words[$key+1]);
}
$sentence = implode(' ', $words);

echo $sentence = str_replace('HYPERLINK ', '', $sentence);
```

Comment: Leave the other non regex solution... I up voted you answer for it lol... It's always good to see more ways to solve a given problem ;-)

Comment: And BTW you could unset both `$key` and `$key+1` so you wont need the `str_replace`... But this will work as long there's no space between the double quotes... The regex solution handles prefectly that case also

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
preg_replace('/HYPERLINK "(.*?)"/', "", $input_string);
```

Comment: That will remove the link itself as well